# Request customer telephone number in sandbox mode - PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on integrating Paypal Express checkout into my site, and am testing locally.

One thing I can't figure out is how to activate it so that I can request a telephone number from the customer in sandbox mode - I've seen on the forums how to do this on production, but would obviously like to test this first.

My code is set up to take the contact number, but no option on the PayPal UI.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly file a PayPal support ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com, add your sandbox account details in the description. Then support team will help you by enabling telephone number field.

Comment: Thanks, I've already spoken to someone from PayPal and it's up and running now.

Comment: Great! Glad to see your comment!

Comment: The support gives you generic US phone number for sandbox: `408-555-5554`.